# In iOS, how do you preserve sharp edges when enlarging a bitmap?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

When you put a `UIImage` into a `UIImageView` that is smaller than the view, and the content mode of the view is `ScaleToFit`, iOS enlarges the bitmap, as expected.  What I have never expected is that it blurs the edges of the pixels it has scaled-up.  I can see this might be a nice touch if you're looking at photographs, but in many other cases I want to see those nasty, hard, straight edges!

Does anyone know how you can configure a `UIImage` or `UIImageView` to enlarge with sharp pixel edges?  That is:   Let it look pixellated, not blurred.

Thanks!

Comment: You can resize the image based on the imageview's width and height.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH Kyokook!  I've been wondering how to do this for years!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to scale up any image in UIImageView with sharpen edge, use the following property of `CALayer`.

```
imageview.layer.magnificationFilter = kCAFilterNearest;
```

It seems that `magnificationFilter` affects an interpolation method of contents of UIView. I recommend you to read an explanation of the property in CALayer.h.

```
/* The filter types to use when rendering the `contents' property of
 * the layer. The minification filter is used when to reduce the size
 * of image data, the magnification filter to increase the size of
 * image data. Currently the allowed values are `nearest' and `linear'.
 * Both properties default to `linear'. */

@property(copy) NSString *minificationFilter, *magnificationFilter;
```

I hope that my answer is useful for you.

Comment: That's great and achieves my purpose, but I want to ask, when I use `magnificationFilter = kCAFilterNearest`, are the big and sharp pixels magnified really the original pixels of the image, or just produced by some processing?Thank you!